# Popping keys of an array to calculate a total

Tags: arrays, perl, file-io

I'm trying to simply pop off each numeric value and add them together to gain a total.

Input file:

```
Samsung   46
RIM       16
Apple     87
Microsoft 30
```

My code compiles, however, it only returns 0:

```
open (UNITS, 'units.txt') || die "Can't open it $!";
my @lines = <UNITS>;
my $total = 0;
while (<UNITS>) {
    chomp;
    my $line = pop @lines;
    $line += $total;
}
print $total;
```

Comment: `my @lines = <UNITS>;` reads all the lines of the file, leaving none for `while (<UNITS>)` to read. Then there's the issue that `pop @lines` makes no sense. You want the last field of a line, not the last line.

Comment: you maybe meant to say while(@lines), but pop @lines returns the whole line, which evaluates to 0, so you would be adding 0 to $total. You need to parse each line for that number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to slurp all lines into an array if you're just going to loop through them anyway with a `while`.  Also, you need to `split` each line to get your numbers.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (UNITS, 'units.txt') || die "Can't open it $!";
my $total = 0;
while (<UNITS>) {
    chomp;
    my $num = (split)[1];
    $total += $num;
}
print "$total\n";

__END__

179
```

Comment: I like the (split)[1], that will help with some problems i'm about to run into. Thanks!

Comment: `(split)[-1]` might be a better guess, as the first column appears to consist of company names, and it is highly likely that it could contain whitespace.

Comment: @Nicktard: Unless you are dealing with only one field of each record, it is far better to extract *all* fields using `my @fields = split` and then pick the data you want from there (in this case `$fields[1]`). Also note my previous comment: if you have spaces in any of your data then a bare `split` will divide single fields into multiple ones.

Answer (score 5):

There are three problems here

- You are trying to add strings like `'Samsung   46' + 'RIM       16'`
- You read the entire file into `@lines` and then try to read more from the file in the `while` loop. That loop is never entered because you have already read to end of file
- You are adding `$total` to the (undeclared) variable `$line` within the loop, instead of the other way around. So `$total` remains at zero and `$line` keeps having zero added to it

It is best to use `while` to read files unless you need something other than sequential access to the records, so removing `@lines` is a start.

It isn't completely clear which part of the records you want to accumulate. This program splits the lines on whitespace and adds together the last field of each line.

You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of every program. It is a measure that will make it far easier to locate bugs in your code. It is also best to use lexical file handles rather than the global one you used, and the three-parameter form of `open`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $units, '<', 'units.txt' or die "Can't open it: $!";

my $total;

while (<$units>) {
  my @fields = split;
  $total += $fields[-1];
}
print $total;
```

**output**

```
179
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $fh, "<", "units.txt" or die "well...";

my $total = 0;
while(<$fh>){
chomp;
my ($string, $num) = split(" ", $_);
$total += $num;
}
print $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a doddle with a one-liner:

```
$ perl -ane '$sum += $F[1] }{ print $sum' units.txt
```

---

**Explanation**

- `-a` enables autosplit, each line is `split` and stored in `@F`
- `-n` loops over the file line by line
- `-e` tells `perl` that the next argument is to be treated as Perl code
- the LHS of the Eskimo-kiss (that funny-looking `}{` in the middle) is performed for every line in the input file, RHS performed only once
- LHS accumulates the second column of every line in `$sum`
- RHS prints the result of `$sum` once all lines have been processed